# Avoid writing duplicate query

Tags: mysql, php

Is there any way to collect somehow or write in another way  query's which is repeted couple of times.
I have a lot of query which are repeted a couple of times, and I dont know to to avoid this issue.
Please dont tell me try to google it, I have alredy try to found solution but unfortunetly I didn't

First query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM attachments
     WHERE project_id = $project_id AND belongs_to = $belongs_to AND isDeleted = 0;";
```

Second query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attachments
     WHERE ClientId = $client_id AND belongs_to = $belongs_to AND isDeleted = 0;";
```

Third query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM attachments
     WHERE project_id = $project_id AND AtaId = $ata_id AND isDeleted = 0";
```

Fourth query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM attachments
     WHERE project_id = $project_id AND Id = $id  AND isDeleted = 0;";
```

Fifth query:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM attachments
     WHERE ClientId = $client_id AND Id = $id AND isDeleted = 0;";
```

Comment: These are not SQL queries, but PHP-statements.

Comment: Yes @Akina. Is there any way to operate these and avoid call same statment multiple times ?

Comment: @ping_pong, from a database point of view these are different statements, and the optimizer may choose different plans for them. If you are asking how to do it in PHP, StackOverflow is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: No, I am asking from Database perspektiv how to do it.

Comment: this is **vulnerable to sql injection** so use only **prepared statemenst with parameters** We don't know nothing about your design nor about what you try to achieve. You would union those queries to get a hole bunch of them on one goal, but as it looks like a bad design or not normalized, you should start by checking the design first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Write 5 PHP subroutines, one for each query.
- Write 1 PHP subroutine and pass in (in the first case) `"belongs_to", $belongs_to`, then construct the query and run it.
- Write 5 SQL Stored Procedures.
- Write 1 SP.  (But this gets rather messy.)

Or... Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to collect somehow or write in another way query's which is repeated couple of times.

I believe the term you're looking for is a "Data Abstraction Layer".

This might take the form of some functions, or some classes with some methods on them, YMMV, but you basically build *something* that runs particular queries when they're called and they hand you back the result.

Other notes:

1. Never use "select *" in Production code.
   It can store up some nasty "Gotchas" for further down the road.
2. Read up about Parameterised Queries (Prepared Statements).  You're *wide open* to SQL Injection Attacks at the moment.  Obligatory XKCD Reference: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)